# white rectangle instead TextureRegion (use libgdx)

Tags: android, textures, libgdx

subjet in the title

loading textures, making

```
private static Map<String, Texture> textureAlreadyLoad = new HashMap<String, Texture>();
```

source of loading

```
String location = tagMap.get("location");
Texture texture;

if(textureAlreadyLoad.containsKey(location)) {
    texture = textureAlreadyLoad.get(location);
} else {
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(location));
    textureAlreadyLoad.put(location, texture);
}

graphic = new StaticGraphic(state, new TextureRegion(texture));
```

support class

```
public class GraphicStorage {
    private Map<Pair<String, State>, ActorGraphic> ActorsGraphic;

    public GraphicStorage() {
        ActorsGraphic = ResourceProvider.getMapGraphic();
    }

    public ActorGraphic getGraphic(String className, State state) {
        return ActorsGraphic.get(new Pair<String, State>(className, state));
    }
}
```

And then I just draw it by the spriteBatch — only 64x64 white rectangles (size of image)
It is a point that I use one image.

Is it good to storage Textures in Map?

Comment: Can you make your question more apparent? It isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: Do you always see white rectangles?  Or only in certain cases (like after switching to another app)?  Storing OpenGL state (like texture references) in static objects (like your map in this example), leads to problems because Java object lifetimes do not match OpenGL object lifetimes ...